# A child is lying on the side of a round footstool. Is it correct to say "Be careful! You may roll yourself onto the floor"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

There is a round footstool with no legs and a child stands the stool up on its side. Then he lies on the side of the footstool as shown in the above picture.

The momentum of the stool may drive the child down onto the floor and he may hurt his head.

Is it correct to say "**Be careful! You may roll yourself onto the floor**"?

Answer (score 3):

Correct, the reflexive "yourself" isn't required. "You may roll onto the floor."

It certainly doesn't sound like the way most people speak to children, you would expect a dialogue:

> What are you up to :-) ;-)?
> rolling.
> okay, well, be careful then.
> why?
> You don't want to roll onto the floor.
> I'm not going to do that.
> alright then.

with "want to" probably spoken as "wanna" and other similar contractions.